# Tag synonym suggestion: [win] -> [windows]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

I noticed we have a [win](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/win) tag.  It is full of fail.

All 4 questions under this tag appears to be from people trying to avoid RSI by not typing the whole word windows, so let's help these poor souls out and make [win](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/win) a synonym for [windows](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/windows) so they can save 4 keystrokes.

---

(I've been on ServerFault for 1 year, 11 months.  This is the first time I've ever had to retag a question to add [windows](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/windows).  I'm not sure if I should be proud, or profoundly concerned)

Comment: Windows is useless without a version tag though. I will deal with these by hand.

Comment: I'm not sure it's useless without a version number (there are some universal concepts - kind of like the [tag:linux] tag), but I'll agree that it's pretty toothless without one :)

Answer (score 1):

### How do you know that it wasn't about winning? Just saying.

Comment: There were windows questions in it - that's obviously fail :-)  (Now if there were questions about freecell or solitaire in it I might be able to get behind it...)